# using a cycle view in top and center a layout - android

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to using a cycle view in top and center a layout.
as you can see, half of this cycle is inside layout and another half is outside of layout.

How can I make it ? using `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout` ?

my orange cycle :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="oval">
   <solid 
       android:color="@color/color_light_main_color"/>
   <size 
       android:width="2dp"
       android:height="2dp"/>    
</shape>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in a ImageView inside a RelativeLayout with "layout_alignParentTop" and "layout_centerHorizontal" to true

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/circle" />
```

Comment: no, half of my cycle view is inside RelativeLayout .